# Plot a red line at a certain point in a bar plot (python3 matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

is it possible to plot a red line in a bar plot to see what values are under or over the lines if the bar graph is huge?
I currently use the following code to plot my bars:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tempA = 'Identifier'
dictionary = frequency_dictionary2.get(tempA)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(150,15))
plt.bar(range(len(dictionary)), dictionary.values(), align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(dictionary)), dictionary.keys(), size='small', rotation='vertical')
plt.title("Frequencies of " + tempA)  
plt.savefig(tempA + ".png", dpi="figure")  

plt.show()
```

Also if anyone knows how can I make a huge bar graph more readable (without grouping variable) would be very grateful.

Comment: You should lookup `axhline`. That probably is what you need.

Comment: thanks, that solved it